# The reason of non-zero TCP window scale option

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I read some stuff about [TCP window scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) and [BDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product)(not quite clear), and I can't figure out what exactly cause sender's TCP realization to set non-zero WS and could the user-mode client program affect it somehow? I think that logically it cannot be based on some data transferring because it happens on SYN-SYN+ACK TCP stage.

Can someone explain from programming point of view, how can user-mode client code affect on TCP window scale option (e.g. before `connect()` call)? And how TCP stack knows when to set WS to non-zero?

Sorry if obvious.

Comment: Also see [TCP receiving window size higher than net.core.rmem_max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31546835/608639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP window scaling index `rcv_wscale` (f.e. while sending *SYN* or *SYN-ACK*) is calculated inside Linux kernel based on socket's receive buffer in function [`tcp_select_initial_window()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.194/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L213):

```
/* If no clamp set the clamp to the max possible scaled window */
if (*window_clamp == 0)
    (*window_clamp) = (65535 << 14);
space = min(*window_clamp, space);

/* Quantize space offering to a multiple of mss if possible. */
if (space > mss)
    space = (space / mss) * mss;
//...
(*rcv_wscale) = 0;
if (wscale_ok) {
    /* Set window scaling on max possible window
     * See RFC1323 for an explanation of the limit to 14
     */
    space = max_t(u32, space, sysctl_tcp_rmem[2]);
    space = max_t(u32, space, sysctl_rmem_max);
    space = min_t(u32, space, *window_clamp);
    while (space > 65535 && (*rcv_wscale) < 14) {
        space >>= 1;
        (*rcv_wscale)++;
    }
}
```

Here `space` is taken from the `tcp_full_space()` based on `sk_rcvbuf`.

Knowing that you can affect this calculation via changing size of receive buffer:

```
int buflen = 12345;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buflen, sizeof int) < 0)
    perror("setsockopt():");
//...
```

This can give you zero scaling (*`WS=0`* or *`wscale 0`*).

P.S. keep in mind that at server side it should be done on listening socket, because you can't affect it after TCP-handshake.