# linux tcp intial rcv window determination

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, window

I read kernel tcp/ip stack code, in function tcp_select_initial_window, there is a judgement I could not understand. The snippet code is as below:

```c
if (mss > (1 << *rcv_wscale)) {
    if (!init_rcv_wnd) /* Use default unless specified otherwise */
        init_rcv_wnd = tcp_default_init_rwnd(mss);
    *rcv_wnd = min(*rcv_wnd, init_rcv_wnd * mss);
}
```

Why do we need to check `mss > (1 << *rcv_wscale)` here? Is there any specific rule for it? I can not find any detailed description in web. could someone give some explanation about this?

Comment: Also see [The reason of non-zero TCP window scale option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58122062/608639) and [TCP receiving window size higher than net.core.rmem_max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31546835/608639)

Comment: @jww, I have also checked the posts you mentioned, they do not refer to the judgement "if (mss > (1 << *rcv_wscale))".

Comment: could any guys give some advices?